# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #: Error inflating class

Tags: java, android, xml, inflate-exception

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/filebinder" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="14"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="30 July"
                    android:textColor="#03a9f4"
                    android:textSize="32sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and i am getting this in my android monitor

```
07-01 18:32:04.693 10005-10005/com.mindefy.kidster E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzb
07-01 18:32:12.293 10005-10005/com.mindefy.kidster E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mindefy.kidster/com.mindefy.kidster.DiaryEntry.diaryEntryTeacherActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

I am a beginner in android and i had read answers of various related questions but still i am not getting it where i am wrong.

Edit 1 - Removed unusual code.

Comment: Have you defined your Activity in manifest file?

Comment: yes i had defined it in manifest

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the Problem is in your `Drawable` Image. The error InflateException is common issue is an out of memory exception when trying to inflate an imageview loading a drawable resource. If one of this resources has a high pixel resolution it would take a lot of memory causing then an inflate exception.

So basically verify that the pixel resolution in your drawables images are just the minimum necessary for your layout.

Comment: thanks @Ironman i had put my image in drawable v-21. i know it was silly but thanks anyways

Comment: i once encountered this problem while working with Android Studion choosing the Navigation template..all what i did was to make use of the drawable while ignoring the drawable v-21 which i think is causing the major problem here

Answer (score 2):

I had this error message, When I was using a library called `com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview`  and i had the image scale type set to `Center_Inside`

which was not supported by the library.  After removing that line in the xml layout it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

`@drawable/filebinder` or `@drawable/diarybookmark` not a valid drawable.

Official doc: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Drawable could be png, jpg, gif files or drawable defined by a XML file as state drawable, shape drawable, ...

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason of this error was that I added the `dimen` resource to `values-land/dimens.xml`, but not in `values/dimens.xml`. Then IDE didn't show any warning/error but at runtime obviously the layout couldn't be drawn.

In general the best way is commenting/deletion views in the layout file one by one to realise which view causes an error.