# android.view.InflateException in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class < unknown >

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try{
        setContentView(R.layout.installation_dialog);//error occured at this line.
```

this is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_custom_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_custom_margin"
    android:layout_weight="0.54"
    card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
    card_view:contentPadding="10dp">


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_Insta_Activities"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etInstaActivities"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="Activity Name"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/accent"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/SpInstaStatus"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.7" />
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_InstaSpentHrs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.3">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etInstaSpentHrs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:hint="Spent Hrs"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:theme="@style/AutocompleteTheme" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_InstaReason"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/LLHrs"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edReworkReason"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ems="11"
                    android:hint="Reason for Rework"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:theme="@style/AutocompleteTheme" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_instal_ok"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/OK"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:theme="@style/CustomButtonStyle"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_instal_cancel"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="@string/Cancel"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:theme="@style/CustomButtonStyle"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have seen some examples on it, and I have tried those solutions. But I did not solve it.[I have studied the solution in this link, but did not resolve the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146238/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-error-inflating-class)

Any one can help me.

Comment: please check your support design gradle version

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'@farhana

Comment: @kalyan You are not using weight properly...check here how to use weight in your views https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use **android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText** as child of **android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout** according to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html).

It will look like:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_InstaReason"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/LLHrs"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/edReworkReason"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="11"
                android:hint="Reason for Rework"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:theme="@style/AutocompleteTheme" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: It is not a problem @maheryhaja

Answer (score 0):

Please check your build.gradle file in which you are adding below line or not:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2' // version is depends on your sdk download.
```

hope this is your issue and if not then please comment below post i will help you to solved your error.